# Data structure in Python for NFA (regex)?

Tags: python, regex, data-structures

I just need a push in the right direction on this.

I am trying to create a class for a nondeterministic finite automaton (NFA) in Python using [Thompson's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction_algorithm).

I'm not sure how to wrap my head around how to arrange this in terms of classes / objects. For a given NFA, it seems clear that we have a "start" and "end" node, and sometimes a start node can point to another start node of a separate NFA, and eventually its end node points to our end node, and so on.

Depending on the type of regex being parsed, it can link the start/end nodes in different ways. And then the edges themselves can have different symbols!

I have no idea how to arrange this correctly. Do I need two classes, one for the node and one for the state machine? Where do I keep the start and end pieces? How do I tell them where they need to "point"? How do I know I am referring to the right node at any given time? How do I label the edges / how do I even store them? Does Python even use pointers this way, or do I have to keep entirely separate "trees" in each node?

Attempt:

```
class NFA_Node():
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = "epsilon"
        self.next = []

class NFA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = NFA_Node()
        self.end = None
        self.start.next.append(self.end)
```

Comment: This particular downvote was probably because you have not presented any previous attempts, shown some code, etc.

Comment: *"I just need a push in the right direction"* is not really a good question for SO. Also, on the commenting on downvotes, see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177/3001761

Comment: @Cu3PO42 Why would it be necessary to post completely unfunctional, incorrectly-arranged code when my question is about asking the right way to do it?

Comment: @user4906860 because it shows everyone you have actually spent time trying to solve this problem and don't just want anyone to do it for you. Also you give the opportunity to comment on certain erroneous parts to help you understand your own mistakes better. If you don't agree with this concept, this may not be the right site for you.

Comment: @Cu3PO42 I posted my current base structure but again I don't know what it will help. I figure once I get the base down correctly it will be easier to add components like union/concatenate/etc.

Comment: @user4906860 that is a start. Now consider letting each node have an isEnd property and think about how you want to store the connections. A tuple, a class?

Comment: @Cu3PO42 I have no clue. I'm not sure how to choose among them because I can't tell how to look ahead and see the type of end goal I need. All I know is how everything needs to inter-link but I don't know how to *arrange* any of it.

Answer (score 1):

(Please don't take this answer as a disagreement with the comments or the downvotes. It's indicative of a soft spot for formal languages.)

Suppose you start with this [nice Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction_algorithm). It has all these nice diagrams that you basically need to translate into code. So, looking at the first diagrams, you can tell that there is more than one type. There's a symbol node and a union node. So you could start off with:

```
class Node(object):
    ...

class SymbolNode(Node):
    ...

class UnionNode(Node):
    ...
```

and so forth.

Now each of the concrete classes probably needs some method

```
    def process(self, input, i):
```

which processes the input at position *i*, but what else do they need? The symbol node needs to know its symbol, so you have

```
class SymbolNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self._symbol = symbol
```

The union node needs the (let's simplify it to) two alternatives. But what would these alternatives be? Other nodes. So we'd have:

```
class UnionNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, opt_a, opt_b):
         self._opt_a, self._opt_b = opt_a, opt_b
```

These are your "pointers" from before.

Presumably, you would eventually come up with the need for other derived nodes, such as a composite node that encapsulates a sequence of nodes, and so forth.

Your Thompson class would hold a `Node` object as well. That's your "pointer" again.

---

There are many many details for you to fill in. Good luck. You might want to check out the Composite design pattern somewhere.

Comment: I am lost on your first step. What are you differentiating between Node, UnionNode and SymbolNode? What are these referring to? And position i? This seems dangerous if the system gets too complex, as we can no longer go with some linearly-increasing id.

Comment: The former is a base class, and the latter two are subclasses. the ``process`` method of ``SymbolNode`` would check that the current symbol of the input is correct, and the ``process`` method of ``UnionNode`` would randomly choose one of its two possibilities, and ask it to process.